# Parsing contents into multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing

I have multiple pdfs in a directory, which I need to parse and store them in multiple dictionaries for each pdf. I am using the following code below to see multiple files in a directory :-

```
files=glob.glob("*.*")
files
```

output:-

```
['HCL_annual_report_2009-10.pdf',
 'HCL_annual_report_2010-11.pdf',
 'HCL_annual_report_2011-12.pdf']
```

code which I need for my help is as follows:-

```
 for file in files:
    y = parser.from_file(file, xmlContent = True)
```

The above should be changed in such a way that the metadata of 1st pdf goes into a dictionary with the name of file as well as the contents. Finally, they need to be zipped into one dictionary. Can anyone suggest me how to do it ?

Comment: where is the problem? you get the solution... make a dictionary file=metadata

Comment: Python cannot read the contents PDF files natively, so you will need to find a third-party module that does that. After you download and install that module you will then be able to use it to construct the dictionary. It's unclear what you mean by "metadata". Python *can* provide file-system related information like file size, date-of-creation from the OS, but again cannot get PDF-related information like Author, Subject, etc.